# Swift equivalent of Java Enum.valueOf

Tags: swift, enums

I found two answered questions about how to get an enum constant's name as a String. I want to do the vice-versa, i.e. getting the enum constant with a given name in a String:

```
enum Unit: Int {
    case SECOND
    case MINUTE
    case HOUR
    
    static func valueOf(unit: String) -> Unit {
        // ?
    }
}
```

I want to keep the `rawValue` to be an `Int`.

Update: To make the intention clear, I want to persist an object that has a `Unit` property. I also want to display the unit chosen by the user in the UI, as a localized string. Therefore I need to assign a constant and unique value, the integer, and a String to each enum value.

Comment: If you want to convert the `String` to `enum` value then set rawValue to `String` instead of `Int`. If you want to map some integer value with your enum value for that you can add a property in your `enum`.

Comment: How do you mean? Stored properties are not allowed in enums. A computed property would need a switch statement, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Yes, I'm taking about computed property only

Comment: added a reason for the question

Comment: In that case, make rawValue as String and simply add computed property for your integer

Comment: See the update. I use the integer as an ID for persistence. A computed property could hold the mapping from ID to the localizable string. I was hoping that I can achieve that without a switch case for each enum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy built-in conversion. You can make the enum [iterable](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID581) and iterate over the strings util you find the correct one:

```
enum Unit: Int, CaseIterable {
    case SECOND
    case MINUTE
    case HOUR

    static func valueOf(unit: String) -> Unit? {
        for x in Unit.allCases {
            if String(describing: x)==unit {
                return x
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

You'd need to deal the the possibility that an input string might not mach any valid case-string.  I used an optional, but you could as well throw an exception.

Several remarks:

- This code is case sensitive. So `"HOUR"` will not lead to the same result as `"hour"`.  If needed, add a case normalisation.
- This code is not optimal, since it will perform a lot of string conversions every iteration on every call.  A better alternative would be to initialise a dictionary once, and use it subsequently

The latter could look like:

```
private static var ready = false
private static var strings = [String : Unit] ()
static func valueOf2(unit: String) -> Unit? {
    if !ready {
        for x in Unit.allCases {
            strings [String(describing: x)]=x
        }
        ready = true
    }
    return strings[unit]
}
```

Comment: Does the job. It's not particularly performant, though. I was thinking about a map from String to Unit instead. That map would have to be initialized somehow (somewhen), and it would mean a lot more code, especially because I want to do this with a number of enums.

Comment: Yep. I'll go for a variant of the latter solution. Thanks.

Comment: An alternative without the bool variable: `private static let names: [String: Unit] = { Unit.allCases.reduce(into: [:]) { $0["\($1)"] = $1 } }()`. And then `static func valueOf(unit: String) -> Unit { names[unit]! }`

Comment: The usage of `reduce` looks a bit better. Also thanks for that one.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Indeed, this is even more compact.  Thanks for the suggestion :-)

Comment: @Christophe right, we were typing at the same time. Although iterating the cases won't slow down my app, I'd prefer a solution with the least possible complexity, regarding performance as well as the amount of source code plus readability.

Comment: @vacawama yes, this would have been my next edit after my quick naive improvement;  but after Joakim's impressive initialisation of the dictionary, I felt it was no longer necessary ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Swift has a `CaseIterable` protocol that you can use to find the case from its raw value.

```
enum Unit: Int, CaseIterable {
    case second = 100
    case minute = 200
    case hour = 300

    static func caseFrom(rawValue: Int) -> Unit? {
        return allCases.first { $0.rawValue == rawValue }
    }
}

if let unitCase = Unit.caseFrom(rawValue: 200) {
    print(unitCase)
}
```

The premise of this enum is a bit confusing to me but this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Read the question OP want to convert string value to an enum

Comment: @NiravD read the last sentence of his question, "I want to keep the rawValue to be an `Int`."

Comment: Yes but I still need e.g. the Unit from the String "MINUTE"

Comment: Then I misunderstood the question. And I would suggest rethinking this approach as what you are asking is not very idiomatic to Swift and seems like an antipattern, IMO.